# How did the model 101 know when and where Legion terminators were going to appear?

Tags: plot-explanation, terminator-series, terminator-dark-fate

Legion and Skynet are two separate AIs, so while I understand that the 101 that killed John Connor no longer had to obey it's mission after Skynet was erased from future existence, I don't see how one of Skynet's products could have any info on Legion's plans.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't find the exact quote, but the T-800 mentions that it can detect "temporal displacements" which let him calculate the exact time and location a Terminator would appear. Then Sarah interrupts him and says "That explains the 'how' but not the 'why'." That's pretty much all the movie does to explain it.

Comment: Importantly, those temporal displacements appeared *in advance* of the time traveler's actual arrival - he could see the wake before the boat arrived, so to speak.

Comment: Love this reponse